# Python How do you resolve a TypeError for < when using len on a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

still learning here and working on my final project for my course. Here's the problem: I'm trying to write to a new file while going through a list and checking another file for these items in the list. If they are found they're supposed to be added to the new file. Right now, I'm getting an TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/jesse/OneDrive/Documents/PycharmProjects/KimmelFreeman_CMIT450_Project/KimmelFreeman_CMIT450_Project.py", line 154, in <module>
        while x < len(list1):
    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I'm trying to check while x is less than the len of the list, to keep checking. I did this because earlier I could only get it return the value of position 0 in the list. Now, I can't get it to work at all. Super frustrating. I've tried adding str() around the len, but then the x+=1 produced an error. Obviously I'm not doing this correctly. I checked for similar posts and couldn't find one, but if there is one, please point me in that direction.

What I expect, the code to run through the list and check it against the input file, if positive results are found, save it to the new file.

I'm not sure which parts you guys need to see, and it's a lot of code so I'll include the area that is producing the error:

```
# Ask user for needed keywords or symbols
user_keywords = input("What keywords or special symbols would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                      "Please separate each entry with a comma.\nIf you would like to just search for question marks,"
                      " please just type n.\n")
# Holding list, using comma as a way to separate the given words and symbols
list1 = list(user_keywords.split(','))
# Print list for user to see
print("You have entered the following keywords and/or special symbols: ", list1)

outFileName = input()
outFile = open(outFileName,'w')

def filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter, key_words):
    key_words_s = set(key_words)
    return filter(lambda l: set(l.split()) & key_words_s, lines_to_filter)

for x in list1:
    outFile.write('Results for keywords and symbols:' + '\n')
    i =0
    while i < len(list1):
        res = filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter= file1lines, key_words= list1)
        outFile.write(str(list(res)))
        i += 1

outFile.close()
```

Let me know if more code needs to be added. Thanks!

**Edit**
Updated to reflect how `list1` is made. I was using the same variables. Rookie mistake. But even when I alter the code and fix the issues for the same variable, I cannot get the code to move off the the first position in the list to look at the other items in it. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you need `int(x)` to convert string to integer. `input()` always returns string - even if you write digits. The same when you read from file - you get string (or bytes) even if you see numbers in file.

Comment: Your list1 obviously contains strings not integers.

Comment: @JānisŠ.Thanks for pointing out what I couldn't originally see... same variable, thus the error! I'm still not moving through the list though and it's only taking the value in position 0 on the list. Any ideas on how to move through the list?

Comment: @bgse Even if I alter the code just to ```res = filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter= file1lines, key_words= list1)
outFile.write(str(list(res)))``` instead of the for and while loop, I'm only getting the value from position 0 in the list.

Comment: @JesseKimmel-Freeman One thing that goes wrong for sure is that you aren't actually changing anything in your two loops except for the value of `x`. You are writing to your output file, but on each iteration you are passing the same values to `filter_lines_by_keywords`. The only thing your loops are doing is influence how many times the exact same function with the exact same input is called.

Comment: You don't show how `list1` is defined. Needs a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey updated code to show how this is list is made.

Comment: Now your code no longer matches the traceback...